# Anti-commutative Hermitian operators in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, anticommutator

An example of a pair of anti-commutative Hermitian operators in a finite Hilbert space is $\sigma_x$ with $\sigma_z.$
Indeed $\sigma_z\sigma_x=i\sigma_y$, whereas $\sigma_x\sigma_z=-i\sigma_y$.
My question is, do there exist pairs of anti-commutative Hermitian operators in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space? That is, Hermitian operators, a and b, satisfying, $[a,b]=2ab.$
If so, please enlighten me with an example!
If not (which is what I suspect), why not?

Comment: Can it be any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space? Or did you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: An infinite direct sum of spaces $\mathbb{C}^2$ immediately produces an infinite dimensional couples of operators satisfying your constraint...

Comment: @probably_someone I'm thinking of operators such as momentum and position.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Surely a commutative space such as $\mathbb{C}^2$ would have $[a,b]=0$. I should have specified that I want nonzero operators too.

Comment: @Henry you are wrong. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the **infinite-dimensional** Hilbert space $H$ over the algebraic direct sum $\oplus_{n=0}^{+\infty} H_n$ where $H_n = \mathbb{C}^2$, equipped with the scalar product $$\langle \{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{n}}| \{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{n}}\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \overline{x_n}^t y_n\:.$$
and the elements of $H$ are the sequences $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ||x_n||^2 < +\infty\:.$$
Next consider the densely-defined Hermitian operators
$$A =  \oplus_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \sigma_z$$
$$B =  \oplus_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \sigma_x$$
with  domain given by the space of definitively vanishing sequences.  It evidently holds on that domain
$$AB = i  \oplus_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \sigma_y$$
and 
$$BA = -i  \oplus_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \sigma_y\:.$$
Thus
$$AB= -BA$$
as required.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example that doesn't involve Pauli matrices?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "doesn't involve Pauli matrices". If $H_1$ is every separable Hilbert space like $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, since $H$ is separable, there is a surjective isometric map $U: H \to H_1$. Thus define $A' := UAU^{-1}$ and $B' := UBU^{-1}$. $A'$ and $B'$ are denseli defined and Hermitian and $A'B'= -B'A'$.

Comment: A natural question is whether or not this is the only example, modulo the choice of $U$. Under some further hypotheses it is...I think, but I do not have much time to think about.

Comment: a related question is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680239/two-operators-x-and-z-in-an-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-space-satisfying-x/1680241#1680241